# Adobe Illustrator: Variation in exported image size based on coordinate position when using Asset Export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

**Note:**

If anyone is coming across this post looking for a solution to asset or artboard exports being off by 1 pixel, Adobe is looking into the issue.

You can vote for a feature request to fix this issue here:
https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-desktop-feature-requests/suggestions/30992416-wrong-exported-image-size-extra-pixel-added-if-a

And you can vote for a bug fix to this issue here:
https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-desktop-bugs/suggestions/48077885-variation-in-exported-image-size-based-on-coordina

---

I'm seeing an issue in the size of an exported image when using Asset Export for Adobe Illustrator v27.5 on Windows 10 22H2. Here's what I've done and the result I'm seeing:

- Create a new empty document, I used an artboard size of 60" x 36" with coordinates (0", 0")
- Add a square to Layer 1 sized to 5" x 5" with a position of (30.5", 20.5")
- Create a new layer, Layer 2
- Add another square to Layer 2 sized to 5" x 5" with a position of (10", 10")
- Select Layer 1 and Layer 2 in the Layers menu
- Then select Collect for Export
- In Asset Export, change the export settings to scale to a resolution of 25 PPI as PNG
- Then export

I had expected I would get 2 images each with dimensions of 125 x 125. Instead, I get one image at 125 x 125 and the other image at 126 x 126.

It seems like the export is rasterized based on the artboard coordinate system instead of the asset's relative coordinate system, which can result in fractional dimensions that round up. Has anyone else noticed this? Is there anything that can be done about it?

Thanks!

[image: Illistrator-Export-Issue]

Comment: Yes the grrid has to start somewhere. Why is this suprising? Snap to the pixel grid?

Comment: Never mind, it turns out this is actually just a 7+ year bug. I'll seek a bug fix through Adobe.

Comment: Just to clarify for @joojaa, it's surprising because 5" x 25 PPI = 125 pixels, not 126. Even more surprising is that if the 5" square is placed at a coordinate of (12.5", 10") then the image is 125 x 126, which is a rectangle and not a square. The coordinates of the graphic don't and shouldn't matter for calculating the exported image size. The only thing that matters is the bounding box dimensions, which for a 5" square is still a 5" square.

Comment: well should or should not. The unfortunate side effect of asking a software to have a pixel preview is that the grid is now fixed to something.